# Don't append a slash to url on page refresh

Tags: html, url

How would I prevent appending a slash to the url when the page refreshes? I have a folder with the same name as the page but I don't want the refresh to make the website go into the folder and the index.php inside the folder. For example, I do not want http://mywebsite.com/blog to become http://mywebsite.com/blog/ which is different page.

How can also I make the folder inaccessible yet readable? I want to keep the name the same.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many possible avenues to do this. Unfortunately, as it is, your question is too broad for Stack Overflow because there are too many possible answers. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of what you have tried that didn't work. Make sure it is Minimal, Complete and Verifiable (read the aforementioned link for more information on what is acceptable as an MCVE).

Comment: I don't get it? Did you use .htaccess to redirect the given link so you want to avoid conflicting with a different directory?